# Heap Corruption After Freeing Memory In C

Tags: c, visual-c++, heap-memory

I have the following piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
    #include <windows.h>
#elif defined __unix__
    #include <unistd.h>
#endif

#define BENCH

#ifndef BENCH
    #define N 10000
#endif

int main(void)
{
#ifdef BENCH
    FILE* output = fopen("out.csv", "w");
    for (int N = 10000; N <= 100000; N += 10000)
#endif
    {
        int* a = malloc(N * sizeof(int));
        if (a == NULL)
            abort();

        for (int i = 2; i < N; i++)
            a[i] = 1;

#ifdef BENCH
        clock_t begin = clock();
#endif

        for (int i = 2; i < N; i++)
        {
            if (a[i])
            {
               #if defined (BENCH) && defined (_WIN32)
                    Sleep(1);
               #elif defined (BENCH) && defined (__unix__)
                    sleep(0.001);
               #endif
               for (int j = i; j <= N / i; j++)
                    a[i * j] = 0;
            }

        }

#ifdef BENCH
        clock_t end = clock();
        double time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        fprintf(output, "%d,%f\n",N ,time_spent);
        free(a); //This is where the corruption occurs
#else
        for (int i = 2; i < N; i++)
        {
            if (a[i])
                printf("%9d ", i);
        }
        puts("");
#endif
    }
#ifdef BENCH
    fclose(output);
#endif
}
```

If `BENCH` is not defined, the program takes a predefined N and displays the results on the console. Performance of the algorithm is not being measured.

if `BENCH` is defined, multiple instances of the problem with different input size`(N)` are being created using the `for` loop. As soon as one instance of the problem finishes, the performance of the algorithm is recorded in the `output.csv` file. Then, the memory allocated for the array of that instance must be freed.

This is where Heap Corruption occurs at least according to what the Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler says on Visual Studio 2019. Does anyone know why this happens ? Both `malloc()` and `free()` seems correct to me. Program works just fine if `free()` is removed.

Comment: The loop condition `j <= N / i` are you sure about it, that it won't lead `i * j` to go out of bounds? Have you tried to step through your code in a debugger to make sure?

Comment: Tested with many N sizes (10^3,10^4,10^5,10^6). With BENCH undefined everything works just fine.

Comment: Just because "everything works fine" doesn't mean it actually does. Undefined behavior have a tendency to work "fine" in some cases, then something insignificant is changed is everything breaks down.

Comment: Regarding the above mentioned loop condition... Lets do a through exercise where we assume `N = 10000` and `i = 2`. Then `N / i` will be `5000`. Your loop with `j` goes from `2` to `5000` inclusive. When `j = 2` then `i * j` is `4`. When `j = 3` then `i * j` is `6`. Etc. Until `j == N / i` (i.e. `j == 5000`). Now the multiplication `i * j` will be `10000`. Which is out of bounds of an array of `10000` elements (remember that array indexes are *zero* based, so an array of `N` elements have indexes from `0` to `N - 1` (inclusive)).

Comment: If your `BENCH` loop started at a smaller value, and your loops would not have to iterate as much and would be easier to debug. This issue would then have been very easy to see when stepping through the code statement by statement.

Comment: You're right, I changed the condition and worked. But I have 2 questions: 1) Why didn't VS detect beforehand that sometime it went out of bounds?  I only received exceptions in free(). 2) That program calculates prime numbers. This code is a modified version of Sedgewick's code. With his version the last number printed was not a prime (eg for N = 10 it printed 9 as the last number which is not a prime.) I guessed it was a typo.

Comment: It is interesting to note that If BENCH is not defined - you don't `free` the array. I'm guessing you do go out of array bounds and VS compiler does check only on `free`. So in case of no BENCH defiled - there is still memory corruption that no-one notices :)

Comment: C don't have any kinds of bounds checking. Some free-standing static analyzer programs might be able to detect this issue, but it's an expensive operation that falls into the realm of undefined behavior, so therefore the compiler don't have to emit a warning about it.

Comment: This does not compile. There is no `Sleep` function. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: It is defined in the windows.h header file. I guess you're running it in linux where probably unistd.h has named it sleep(). Good notice.

Comment: It is not needed to demonstrate the problem. None of this benchmark stuff is needed. Remove it. [You will need 10 seconds to find the problem](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b3f776950f8673e9).

Comment: My main concern was the heap corruption. I have not described exactly what my main goal is.Nevertheless, I'll make the edit so it can be compiled successfully in linux too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was finally located in the termination condition of the loop `for (int j = i; j <= N / i; j++)` and not in `free()`. Changing it to `for (int j = i; j < N / i; j++)` solved the heap corruption problem.

As *Some programmer dude* pointed in the comments, an Out Of Bounds Exception was occurring without the debugger notifying me. Having being in Visual Studio where I mostly write C# code, I had the illusion that if something went wrong I would at least receive the exception in the line where the bad things would happen.

That's **not** the case since C doesn't have any kind of bounds checking. Undefined behavior have a tendency to work "fine" in some cases, then something insignificant is changed is everything breaks down. As *AbbysSoul* pointed, heap corruption was occurring in all cases, even with `BENCH` undefined. When a critical operation like `free()` invoked on a corrupted heap, the process was doomed to crash.

The big lesson here is to check all lines of code in a C program, **especially** when you don't see any error in the line where the exception occurs.